# SELECT INTO a temporary table then drop on commit

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to `SELECT INTO` a temporary table and drop the temporary table on commit.

I can do

```
BEGIN;
SELECT
foo, bar
INTO TEMPORARY TABLE foo_table
FROM bar_table
COMMIT;
```

but the temporary table persists for the lifetime of the session.

I can create the temporary table separately:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo_table
(foo varchar, bar int)
ON COMMIT DROP;
SELECT foo, bar
INTO foo_table
FROM bar_table;
COMMIT;
```

but it's not as nice, because I need to specify the column names and types of the temporary table myself.

Is it possible to do `ON COMMIT DROP` with `INTO TEMPORARY TABLE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use (the recommended) [`create table as`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) syntax:

```
create temporary table foo_table
  on commit drop 
as
SELECT foo, bar
FROM bar_table;
```